# User Adding/Using Self Image

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, assets

A photo will be added as seen in the picture, but the user using this application will add it herself.
[image]

i'm new to flutter and i guess permission should be asked just to solve this problem, if you want i can share my code too

Comment: you need to provide[minimal-reproducible-example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , For this you can use [`image_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package : [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

See also example code defined in this package for your understanding

Comment: Thank you I solved my problem with the package you said

Comment: Great!!! @Baris